# cli script search and calculate words in file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, command-line-interface

I have file with strings like

```
    object-group network NAME1
    object-group network OTHERNAME2
    .....
    object-group network OTHERNAME5
    ....
    ... NAME1 ..... 
    ..... OTHERNAME2 ... NAME1  ...... 
    .......
```

and I would like to know how many times words  NAME1, OTHERNAME2, .... OTHERNAME5 consist file. I do not know words but string start from "object-group network "

```
input file example
 object-group network NAME1
 object-group network NAME2
 object-group network NAME3
 object-group network NAME4
 ....
word word word NAME1 word word
word word word NAME1 word NAME2
word word word NAME3 word word word
word word word NAME1 word NAME3 word NAME2
...

output require
NAME1 4
NAME2 3
NAME3 3
NAME4 1
```

Comment: do you know the words you want to check for the occurrence? are the words fixed or also dynamic? if dynamic, what is the rule of those keywords?

Comment: I don't know words name but is always third word in line

Comment: object-group network  <WORD>

Comment: A bunch of `...`s in your sample input does nothing but clutter it up and make it untestable. Get rid of them and provide something we could test a potential solution against. This is not a job for sed at all (no variables and so no way to count), it's a job for awk so tag your question as such.

Answer (score 0):

awk is happy to do this kind of job:

```
awk '/^object-group network/{a[$3]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
```

I made an example to test:

```
kent$  cat f
object-group network NAME1
object-group network NAME2
this line would be skipped NAME
object-group network NAME1
object-group network NAME2
object-group network NAME1
object-group network NAME3
object-group network NAME3
object-group network NAME2

kent$  awk '/^object-group network/{a[$3]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' f
NAME1 3
NAME2 3
NAME3 2
```

### update for new comments:

```
awk '/^object-group network/{a[$3]++;next}
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in a)a[$i]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}' file
```

**Note that this line works if no leading spaces/tabs before** `object-group network`. If you do have leading spaces, add `\s*` after `^`

Comment: "object-group network NAME1" is unique, but  NAME1 can use in other strings below in file.

Comment: @uatousa you know what, you gave an example with many "dots", I have to guess, what text do you have and what output are you expecting. after reading your comments under the question. I came up with this answer. So please give an input and output example which could describe your requirement clearly, it can save a lot of PING-PONG!

Comment: I added example input/output